# createPattern not returning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, variable-types, jcanvas

I am getting a TypeError on the variable "pattern" and my script does not execute past the marked break point. I am using the JCanvas and JQuery and all dependencies are in place. What is the reason for the error. There is a similar implementation used [here](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox.php#function%20draw%28patt%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%24%28%22canvas%22%29.drawEllipse%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fillStyle%3a%20patt,%0A%20%20%20%20x%3a%20200,%20y%3a%20100,%0A%20%20%20%20width%3a%20250,%20height%3a%20100%0A%20%20%7D%29;%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20patt%20=%20%24%28%22canvas%22%29.createPattern%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20source%3a%20%22images/water.jpg%22,%0A%20%20%20%20repeat%3a%20%22repeat%22,%0A%20%20%20%20//%20Draw%20ellipse%20when%20pattern%20loads%0A%20%20%20%20load%3a%20draw%0A%7D%29;).

```
function drawMe(thumbUrl){
  function drawThumb(){
    $("canvas").drawRect({
      //Code breaks here.
      fillStyle: pattern,
      x: 200, y: 100,
      width: 250, height: 100,
      fromCenter: false         
    });
  }

  var pattern = $("canvas").createPattern({
    source: thumbUrl,
    repeat: "repeat",
    load: drawThumb
  })

}

drawMe("http://placehold.it/100x100");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to change this

```
function drawThumb(){
    $("canvas").drawRect({
      //Code breaks here.
      fillStyle: pattern,
      x: 200, y: 100,
      width: 250, height: 100,
      fromCenter: false         
    });
  }
```

to this

```
function drawThumb(pattern){
    $("canvas").drawRect({
      //Code breaks here.
      fillStyle: pattern,
      x: 200, y: 100,
      width: 250, height: 100,
      fromCenter: false         
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don´t think so. 'pattern' is a var defined later on. But there´s something completely mixed up. The var-definition references to 'thumbUrl' which is not defined previously but is defined as a function parameter before. I would say: restructure your code, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Chrome. After restarting chrome it solved me the problem...